# Laravel - Sqlsrv Remote Connection

Tags: sql-server, laravel

I am trying to connect to the sql server database on the remote server with Laravel, but I could not do it, I made all the necessary settings as follows:

`php.ini` settings

```
    extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64
    extension=php_sqlsrv_81_ts_x64
```

`database.php` settings

```php
         'sqlsrv' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'IP ADRESS'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'DATABASE NAME'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'UID'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'UPW'),
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'prefix' => '',
            'prefix_indexes' => true,
            // 'encrypt' => env('DB_ENCRYPT', 'yes'),
            // 'trust_server_certificate' => env('DB_TRUST_SERVER_CERTIFICATE', 'false'),
```

The error I get is like this

> PDOException::("SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64:

Comment: you can do `phpinfo()` or just `phpinfo(INFO_MODULES);` to get the list of enabled modules. also make sure it is enabled in the cli version of your php.ini

Comment: everything seems ok but i can't solve the problem somehow :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to install an ODBC from the official page:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).